# How to automate login to Google OAuth to access known user account

Tags: android, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

I am using google firebase oAuth in my app for login 
My problem is that everytime i open the app it ask to login .
I want to automate using token service but i dont know how to and what to do.

```
private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 0 ;
private static String TAG = "LOGIN_ACTIVITY";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
Context context = LoginActivity.this;
public FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private EditText mEmailField,mPasswordField;
TextView register;
private String Email ;
Model_userDetails model_userDetails = new Model_userDetails(); ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    register = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user!=null) {

               // new HttpCall().checkGoogleEmail(context, Email);

            }

            else
                Log.d("AUTH","User logged out");
        }
    };


    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)).requestEmail().build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this,this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso).build();

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,NewUserActivity.class));
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener !=null)
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==RC_SIGN_IN)
    {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

        if (result.isSuccess())
        {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            Email = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
            new HttpCall().checkGoogleEmail(context, Email);
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG,"Google login failed ");

    }
}



private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct){
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(),null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d("AUTH","sign in with credentials: complete "+ task.isSuccessful());
        }
    });
}



private void signIn()
{
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent,RC_SIGN_IN);
}

  private void emailSignIn()

{
    String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)||  TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
    {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Fields are empty ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "Please wait...", "Proccessing...", true);

        (mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password))
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AccountActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("Email", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                            startActivity(i);
                        } else {
                            Log.e("ERROR", task.getException().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }
                });}

}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG," Connection Failed");

}
```

This is my code
please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

i got it myself . We have to call the new activity when checking if the user is login or not.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(user!=null) {

           new HttpCall().checkGoogleEmail(context, Email);

        }

        else
            Log.d("AUTH","User logged out");
    }
};
```